# I want to parse a string to xml in java and write that to a xml file

Tags: java, xml

the file should be like this

```
<root>
     <node label="ValueFromDatabase"/>        
</root>;
```

and there will be more node labels that i will take form database the label is variable.

Actually I should have made the question more clear. I used the string like this

```
String xmlSourceResource =
             "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n"+
             "<root>\n"+
             xmlString+
             "</root>";
```

the xmlString variable contains the nodes with label.Now, I'm parsing it to xml like this

```
StringWriter xmlResultResource = new StringWriter();
Transformer xmlTransformer=TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();    
xmlTransformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlSourceResource)),new StreamResult(xmlResultResource));
```

and I need this in an Flex action script class in an XML variable.So, how should I parse it or send the XML to flex if it is possible.I dont want to make a XML file.

Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: The trailing `;` makes the XML invalid

Comment: try JAXB. It will help you convert your java object to xml

Comment: Not only the `;` is the problem as there is no xml declaration in the 1st row. Putting that aside: no one said that it is an object which need to be serialized to XML, but we do know that the data is from a DB, so I would suggest `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` instead of JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author ugo_dock
 */
public class JavaToXML {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Myself myself = new Myself();

    myself.setAge(48);
    myself.setFirstName("Barry");
    myself.setLastName("White");

    try{
    JAXBContext jAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Myself.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jAXBContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(myself, System.out);
    }
    catch(JAXBException e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
}

@XmlRootElement
class Myself{


private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
@XmlElement
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
@XmlElement
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}


}
```

And the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <myself>
    <age>48</age>
    <firstName>Barry</firstName>
    <lastName>White</lastName>
</myself>
```